# switch two view controller's view in a cube animation

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

the code below implement the switch between two view in a cube animation .

```
UIViewController* viewCtrl = [[UIViewController alloc] init:book];

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 1;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = @"cube";
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
transition.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewCtrl animated:YES];    

[viewCtrl release];
```

but, if the view don't belong to self.navigationController, how to do switch in cube animation between two view controller, and then how to scale the current view controller's view in the same time?  thanks very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
-(IBAction)animate:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"animate");

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.delegate = self;
    transition.duration = 0.8;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    NSString *types[4] = {@"cube", @"rippleEffect", @"cube", @"alignedCube"};
    NSString *subtypes[4] = {kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromRight};

    transition.type = types[0];
    transition.subtype = subtypes[1];

    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

    SecondView *_secondViewController = [[SecondView alloc]initWithNibName:@"secondView" bundle:nil];
    self.secondViewController = _secondViewController;
    _secondViewController = nil;

    [[[self view] layer] addAnimation: transition forKey: nil];
    [[self view] addSubview: [self.secondViewController view]];
}

-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag{
    [self.view release];
}
```

Comment: Note that all of the 'types' above are undocumented and if you are discovered using them your app might get pulled. Also, they might go away (or get renamed) in any point release.