# cube structure view controllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview

I am looking to build an app that has 6 view controllers laid out in a cube structure (instead of having a tab bar for navigation...). I used this example to make the cube transitions: [switch two view controller's view in a cube animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559777/switch-two-view-controllers-view-in-cude-animation)

However, most of the examples (another one: [how does the CATransition work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973983/how-does-the-catransition-work)) show how to transition between UIViews rather than UIViewControllers, which is what I am interested in.

My questions are: how do I use CATransition to transition between UIViewControllers, and also - how do I go back from one UIViewController to another assuming that I am using the pushViewController: method (so far I have been using  presentModalViewController: and get back (say, for cancel) used this method dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use CATransition to switch between two view controllers, but you can simply use the view controller's view and switch it with another view controller's view.

iOS 5 made transitioning with UIViewControllers easier as it introduces the `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:` method.

In the end, you'll still be using the UIViews of the UIViewControllers.

(Actually, the link you provided is exactly how you transition between two UIViewControllers. Remember, view controllers only manage views and aren't really views themselves. Switching back won't be as easy as dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: but sometimes customization isn't easy).

Here's an example with using the iOS 5 method:

UIViewController *controller = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [controller.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

```
[self addChildViewController:controller];

[self transitionFromViewController:self.redController toViewController:controller duration:0.8 options:0 animations:^{
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.delegate = self;
    transition.duration = 0.8;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    NSString *types[4] = {@"cube", @"rippleEffect", @"cube", @"alignedCube"};
    NSString *subtypes[4] = {kCATransitionFromLeft, kCATransitionFromRight, kCATransitionFromTop, kCATransitionFromRight};

    transition.type = types[0];
    transition.subtype = subtypes[1];

    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [controller didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}];
```

Note, you'll have to do the following beforehand.

```
[self addChildViewController:self.redController];
[self.view addSubview:self.redController.view];
```

There are a few things you have to do before using these methods. The main difference is that you're going to have one more view controller than you current have. This extra UIViewController serves as a container for the other two (kind of like how currently, self.view is a container for the two UIViews you have).

Comment: so if I have two different views (say an activity feed and a user account info) should I use one UIViewcontoller with two views or two view controllers and utilize their two UIviews?

Comment: It depends on you, actually. The general tip is that if they're both fullscreen (on say an iPhone) then they should be two different UIViewControllers, but in terms of coding, it's easier if they both share the same UIViewController. Personally, I'd go with two separate UIViewControllers as they seem like they are separate.

Comment: thats nice and makes sense, but I dont see how I can use transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion with a cube style transition

Comment: You'd simply put the animation code in the animations block. I've updated my answer (but remember, you're still dealing with the UIViewControllers' views)

Comment: whats redController? thanks a bunch, i'll try it out and get back to you. +1 for now :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. It was just an example I was testing (I always test code before posting =). In this code, "redController would be the current UIViewController that's being displayed. "controller" would be the one you want to animate to.

Comment: sorry for all the questions, but which viewcontroller is the present one? I am subclassing a UIViewController, so i think it should be just "self" but i get errors...thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh yes, I should have probably been more clear. This whole concept of `transitionFromViewController:` is so developers can create UIViewController **containers**. "self" is actually the container (just like UINavigationController, UITabBarController, and UISplitViewController) for the other two UIViewControllers. So you would type all the code that's in the answer inside a custom UIViewController subclass. You'd then add the present view controller as a subchild as well as its view. In my example, the present view controller is "self.redController"

Comment: mmm...now i am really confused :) my app has two viewcontrollers, and i am planning to call this code from within the IBAction that meant to be switching the UIViewcontroller. What is a custom UIViewController subclass in that case? sorry again for all those questions...i think i am missing here something very fundamental..

Comment: Honestly, the added iOS 5 methods didn't do much other than being more conceptually correct, automatic forwarding of rotation methods, and set the parentViewController property of the UIViewController as well as added the childViewControllers property. In terms of animation, you'll still be manipulating the views the same way.

Comment: Haha, it's alright. I didn't expect you to want to use iOS 5 and newer only methods.

Comment: If you want to use `transitionFromViewController:`, you'll have to actually create a whole new UIViewController file to serve as a container (just like how UITabBarController and UINavigationControllers are containers). In this container file is where you'll have both your view controllers created and that's where you'll switch from one to another. In terms of Interface Builder, you'll probably have a UIViewController xib, then have two more UIViewController objects in that xib which points to the activity feed and the user info.

Comment: All together you'll have three UIViewControllers, so one more than you started with.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it - so I cant manage with only two view controllers files (2 .m files and 2 .h files)...In my case I do all programmatically and dont use IB. Ok, I'll try now adding a container view controller. thanks!

Comment: if i do that - which UIViewcontroller does the appDelegate suppose to call? the container? and how does it know which view to present first? I used to call the first view controller straight from the app delegate

Comment: Well, think of the container like a UITabBarController or a UINavigationController. The App Delegate would call the container view controller. The container view controller then manages the two view controllers you're trying to animate. It works exactly like UIViews as well. Think of self.view as the container and activityFeedView and userInfoView as the two subviews.

Comment: The container itself has to present the first one, so in viewDidLoad of your container, you'd create the first view controller, add it as a childViewController, then add the first view controller's view to self.view.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I saw that in the WWDC videos, and realized that I am doing things very differently, but your explanation was really helpful. Let me check it and get back to you...thanks a tons. throwing you some more +1...:)

Comment: By the way - whats the meaning of the .XIB file of the container view controller if I only use it as a container for two other view controllers? (I started a project that is a single view template)

Comment: Ok I did it, but now - how do I trigger transitionFromViewController method in the countainer view controller if I am running the code of one of the children view controllers?

Comment: The great thing about using view controllers is that you can simply use `[self.parentViewController transitionFromViewController...`