# Cube animation between view controllers iOS 6

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, core-animation

I want to create an app with 6 views like the sides of a cube, and be able to swipe in each direction to move to another side of the cube.

So I want an animation between view controllers that looks like a cube being rotated.

Some old posts (eg [cube structure view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829504/cube-structure-view-controllers)) mention the use of @"cube" for the transition type to use in a CATransition, and call UIViewController's transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion method to easily animate between two view controllers.

However, the iOS 6 documentation and header files make no mention of using @"cube" or any other of the string literals mentioned in the old (iOS 5 era) posts.

And I can't find anything about that being deprecated in the iOS 6 release notes or API diffs.

The animation works, but I'm worried my app will be rejected if I use it.

Will it? What's the alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from here:

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/102300-undocumenten-catransition-type.html

"I asked Apple's engineers about this specific issue. They said that officially, undocumented transition effects are just like any other undocumented API feature, and are not allowed.

However, their automated tools are not set up to detect using undocumented transitions like they are using undocumented methods, so you may get away with it, and you may not. It's a gamble."